# PayPal payment for InApp contents on Android using WebView or External browser

Tags: android, paypal, payment-gateway, payment-processing

If I collect PayPal payment for InApp contents on Android using WebView or External browser, is it okay with the Google's TOS?

Comment: Not sure, but I think you have to use their payment system. AFAIK, they don't offer support for paypal payments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is an easy way other to create a link to the paypal donation page. However, I believe it is OK to do this as long as you are not providing any extra features (i.e. your app doesn't change) after the donation.

If you want the app to provide extra functionality after a donation then you should use the google in app billing or create a pro version of the app.